Cannot select specific element from the html with `rvest`
I want to capture this download link (href attribute) in the line 406 from site: https://www.fda.gov/drugs/drug-approvals-and-databases/drugsfda-data-files, there should be an attribute 'data-entity-substitution' in this html, but when I used html_element, it gave me a missig value.

Here is my code:
html <- rvest::read_html("https://www.fda.gov/drugs/drug-approvals-and-databases/drugsfda-data-files")
rvest::html_element(html, "[data-entity-substitution]")
#> {xml_missing}
#> <NA>


Somehow I'm not able to reproduce this and your selector works  for me (RStudio, interactive session). Have you checked content of that response? You can save it to a file for inspection with xml2::write_html(html, "tmp.html")

Thank you for your assistance. However, I encountered an issue as the content is not complete in my current situation, specifically due to the absence of the [data-entity-substitution] node. The reason behind this remains unclear to me. Nonetheless, I have resolved the problem by recognizing that the FDA drug URL remains static. Consequently, I can consistently utilize the URL https://www.fda.gov/media/89850/download?attachment without the necessity of scraping the website.

In this case there is no need to scrape anything! You can use download.files to download the zip file and unzip. I read them into a list since the data does not have the same number of columns
library(tidyverse)

temp = tempfile(fileext = '.zip')

url = 'https://www.fda.gov/media/89850/download?attachment'

download.file(url, temp, method = 'auto',
              mode = 'wb')

temp2 = tempfile()

dt = unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2 )


dat = map(dt, \(x) read_delim(x, delim = '\t'))
#> Rows: 59 Columns: 4
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (3): ActionTypes_LookupDescription, SupplCategoryLevel1Code, SupplCatego...
#> dbl (1): ActionTypes_LookupID
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Rows: 74017 Columns: 8
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr  (4): ApplNo, SubmissionType, ApplicationDocsTitle, ApplicationDocsURL
#> dbl  (3): ApplicationDocsID, ApplicationDocsTypeID, SubmissionNo
#> dttm (1): ApplicationDocsDate
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Warning: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details,
#> e.g.:
#>   dat <- vroom(...)
#>   problems(dat)
#> Rows: 27412 Columns: 4
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (3): ApplNo, ApplType, SponsorName
#> lgl (1): ApplPublicNotes
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Rows: 62 Columns: 2
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (1): ApplicationDocsType_Lookup_Description
#> dbl (1): ApplicationDocsType_Lookup_ID
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Rows: 48269 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (2): ApplNo, ProductNo
#> dbl (1): MarketingStatusID
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Rows: 5 Columns: 2
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (1): MarketingStatusDescription
#> dbl (1): MarketingStatusID
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Warning: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details,
#> e.g.:
#>   dat <- vroom(...)
#>   problems(dat)
#> Rows: 47798 Columns: 8
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (6): ApplNo, ProductNo, Form, Strength, DrugName, ActiveIngredient
#> dbl (2): ReferenceDrug, ReferenceStandard
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Rows: 28 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (2): SubmissionClassCode, SubmissionClassCodeDescription
#> dbl (1): SubmissionClassCodeID
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Rows: 266557 Columns: 5
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (3): ApplNo, SubmissionType, SubmissionPropertyTypeCode
#> dbl (2): SubmissionNo, SubmissionPropertyTypeID
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Rows: 182145 Columns: 8
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr  (5): ApplNo, SubmissionType, SubmissionStatus, SubmissionsPublicNotes, ...
#> dbl  (2): SubmissionClassCodeID, SubmissionNo
#> dttm (1): SubmissionStatusDate
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> Rows: 22944 Columns: 4
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (3): ApplNo, ProductNo, TECode
#> dbl (1): MarketingStatusID
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

Created on 2024-07-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you for your assistance. I was previously unaware that the URL I am referring to will remain unchanged.
In the process of searching for alternative codes to help me download FDA drugs data, I came across a repository in https://github.com/jason-fries/drugsatfda-db which was created three years ago. it is worth mentioning that the current URL remains identical to the one mentioned here, indicating that there will be no modifications made to it when FAD updated.
